# How to access php session in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

Below is my code:

index.php file

javascript of index.php file

```
function Result()
{
  var marks = 55;
  document.getElementById("hdnmarks").innerHTML= marks; 
  window.location = "results.php";
}
```

HTML of index.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnmarks" id="hdnmarks">
```

**Description:** I have a web page with url `localhost/index.php`. In index.php, I have a submit button on the click of which I call `Result` javascript method which sets the marks = 55 and put it into the hidden field and takes me to the `results.php` page.

In `results.php`, I have to insert value of marks in the database. But how should I access the marks as those were stored in the hidden field of `index.php` file?

I want to put marks in the session, but how should I maintain the PHP session in javascript function? I mean where and when should I put marks in the session before moving to `results.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start session on your page like `<?php session_start();?>` and create hidden field for session like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="mysession" id="mysession">
```

and modify javascript function some thing like this

```
function Result(){
  var marks = 55;
  document.getElementById("mysession").innerHTML= <?php echo session_id();?>; 
  document.getElementById("hdnmarks").innerHTML= marks; 
  document.getElementById('Form').submit();
}
```

change the Form name with your form name

Comment: How can I assign marks in the session in this javascript function in index.php so that I can use that session in results.php?

Comment: use $_SESSION['marks'] = 55; to assign any value but make sure your session is started session_start() on top of the page.

Comment: You are saying me to set marks in the session in the php code but as per my requirement when I come to javascript Result function, I have to do something and then redirect to another page. So I have to set the session in that javascript function not in the php code.

Comment: You can reassign the value again, after doing something But you don't need to start session again. session would started once on a page.

Comment: So will this code inside Result function work? <?php  $_SESSION['marks'] = $marks; ?> NOTE: I have already started the session on the top of php page. I just want to know where should I assign the marks session?

Comment: yes it will work everywhere but varible $marks should have value;

Comment: No, it does not work when I write it in my javascript function. By writing it and again refreshing the page, even existing javascript functions don't work. Instead of $marks, I am directly assigning 55 to session. Nothing is working.

Comment: Actually its very big and I am working on only some portion of it. But what code snippet I have give to you, I think its clearly reflecting what I want to ask?

Answer (score 2):

your question have two parts

1)

> But how should I access the marks as those were stored in the hidden
>   field of index.php file?

the standard way is using a form

```
<form action="index.php" method=POST>
  <input type="hidden" name="hdnmarks" id="hdnmarks">
</form>
```

submit that form using a button or javascript to POST data to index.php

*in index.php*

```
<?php

$marks = $_POST['hdnmarks'];

?>
```

2)

> I mean where and when should I put marks in the session before moving
>   to results.php?  you have to start session and make a session variable

*index.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$marks = $_POST['hdnmarks'];
$_SESSION['marks'] = $marks;
?>
```

*result.php*

```
<?php session_start() ?>
...
//javascript code
var marks = <?php echo $_SESSION['marks'] ?>
...
```

NOTE: this isnt a very good way of passing data from one to another nor a good way of passing data from php to javascript and if you are using a database, session has no use in this as well

Comment: Can I write  <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['marks'] = $marks;
    ?> in my javascript function "Result"?

Comment: yeah thats basically what i've written above :S

Comment: Standard position to start session is top of the page you can't start it like that

Comment: as long as it is at the top of the page there's no problem :S
@nkp oh now only i got what you asked, no you cant put session_start with the rest of in inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Just Javascript Use This:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

getCookie('PHPSESSID');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can access the php `$_SESSION` from javascript provided that the javascript code that access the session is included within a `.php` file. This kind of javascript code is called inline javascript.

// `index.php`

```
<html>

  <script>
     const userId = '<?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?>'
     console.log('The user id is', userId)
  </script>
  <script src="other.js"></script>

</html>
```

// `other.js`

```
console.log('Once again, the user id is', userId)
```

The html that will be generated will have a script with the userId already set.
The variable can be accessed from other scripts that come after the inline script.